# ListView pagination for images

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have made a Picasa type application using asp.net that uses the `ListView` control to display images in the browser.

All the images are appearing perfectly fine. It takes images directly from a server folder and instantly display in thumbnails. When any of the image is being clicked it uses jQuery to display that particular image in big size. Then it can be closed.

However, there is a problem. if there are more than 100 images in a single server folder, it skips few images and displays blank x there. So I decided to paginate 40 images per page. How can I do that in `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a [`DataPager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control inside the [`LayoutTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of your `ListView`.

You can add it like this:

```
<asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="40">
    <Fields>
      <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10"
           PreviousPageText="<--"
           NextPageText="-->" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that uses a DataPager control (with downloadable demo/source) - https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx#postadlink